# Is the external storage size limit hardware or software?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, storage

AFAIK, All phones I know have a SD Card size limit. Is this hardware, or software ?

If this is hardware, what changes between, let's say a 32GB card, and a 64GB card ?

If this is software, is this just an arbitrary limit, or the system really won't be able to read it ? Is this changable (Custom ROM, Kernel) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know, this is a software limit. The communication protocol of a 32GB, 64GB or even 128GB SD card is exactly the same. Only the old non HC or XC cards of 2GB or less uses a different communication protocol. The reason that some devices doesn't support 64GB or bigger is due to the use of the exFAT file system on cards of 64GB and larger. Although, if you reformat this cards to the older FAT32 file system you can use in a device that officially supports up to 32GB cards (only in very rare cases it still doesn't work). My experience is that a 128GB card formatted in FAT32 works without issues in a Samsung Galaxy S2 that officially supports up to 32GB.

Comment: A kind of clarifcation (all 64GB or 128GB must be accessible if formatted as FAT32) -- https://android.stackexchange.com/a/155396/13117 by blunden:  ...as long as the user reformatted the cards as FAT32 (or another supported filesystem I imagine). The SDXC standard mandates that the cards are sold formatted as exFAT but the standard also includes backward compatibility with SDHC devices, albeit at slightly lower speeds.